# How to get optional image to be displayed on main page if available?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have my new site at virmodrosti.com which has code to grab first image from latest post and use it for big image on the main site.

```
<div class="imgwide" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), url(<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center;">
```

the command is `<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>`

How can I use optinal image instead of first image if available?
Currently my images order are /location/image240.jpg, image241.jpg, image242.jpg etc. So I would like to add optional image that can be used if available,
for example, if I upload aditional images like image240wide.jpg, image241wide.jpg, image242wide.jpg to image location. how can I make that it will display the wide image and then normal if wide is not available?

I will just make big custom format myself and upload them to location of images.
Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: `if (file1 exists) showIt() else showAnotherFile()`

Comment: well if anyone know something kindly let me know